# How can I make URLs automatically hyperlinked on a web-published Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs, links

When I publish Google Docs to the web like this: https://docs.google.comView?id=dc7gj86r_22pv9qqffp I can manually turn a URL into a hyperlink as I did on the first two, but how can I make Google Docs automatically turn the URLs in my text into hyperlinks when the text is published as a web page?

[image]

Comment: Doesn't Google Docs automatically do this for you now?

Comment: Don't have permission to see your sample document. Is this still an issue?

Answer (score 2):

<sub>It seems that right now, in 2018, it's the default behavior.</sub>

---

**The link detection gets triggered when you enter a space or press enter after pasting or writing the URL.**
So, if you paste a URL that has space at the end of it - it won't automatically detect it (at least not at first), and will treat it as simple text. 
For example "https://google.com ".

You can verify this setting under *Tools --> Preferences*:

[image]